# pdflatex stops when both german and hungarian languages are set in babel

Tags: pdftex, babel, catcodes, german, hungarian

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,hungarian]{babel}

\begin{document}

babel test

\end{document}
```

When I run pdflatex on this MWE the program stops with:

```
pdflatex babel-test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./babel-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-10>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/german.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hungarian/magyar.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./babel-test.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls) [1{/usr/local
/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./babel-test.aux
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \hskip
l.4 \catcode `"
               \active
?
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?
I have freshly installed TeXLive 2022 on linux.

Thanks.

Comment: @daleif - Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

magyar.ldf patches the (internal) latex command `\@begindocumenthook` to inject some code into the aux-file:

```
{\toks@\expandafter{\expandafter\@@magyar@protect@backtick\@begindocumenthook}%
   \xdef\@begindocumenthook{\the\toks@}}% Dat: \@begindocumenthook has #1 #2 etc.
```

With the introduction of the new hook system in latex this no longer works as intended. The catcode change is to late.

The author has been notified two years ago about this but magyar.ldf has not been adapted.

As a work-around you can reset the problematic catcode before \begin{document}:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german,hungarian]{babel}

\AddToHook{begindocument}[test]{\catcode\string``=12 }
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{test}{before}{babel}

\begin{document}
babel test
\end{document}
```

I removed the inputenc line as it is no longer needed: utf8 is the default since a few years.

Comment: Using your example I am still getting the same error.

Comment: did you delete the old aux-file?

Comment: I copied your example code to a new tex file, there was no aux file. I also checked that the bactick is backtick in the copied text. If I delete the aux file generated by the first run and run pdflatex again I get the error again.

Comment: I changed the code, I don't know why I thought a simple catcode would work (but you should contact the author, magyar should really be adapted).

Comment: OK, the new code compiled without error. Thank you.